# How to align objects on a map to an invisible grid?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a Google Map where I use overlays as a substitute of rich text markers. Thank's to that I can use HTML inside along with CSS, background images and still position my "markers" (custom overlays) by converting lat & lng to CSS top & left on map. How I do this? I simply crete new object and then I override `draw` method.

`foo.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();`

and

```
foo.prototype.draw = function () {

    // cut off
    var bar = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng)
    // cut off

}
```

Everything works fine so far.

The point is that I would like to learn how I can achieve below effect?

[image]

Do you see how markers are aligned? Something like a grid of points (markers). This effect is awesome and achievable - [this is the evidence](https://deutschland25.withgoogle.com/de_DE/home). So basically how this is possible? All I have is precise latitude and longitude of each point. First thing that came to my mind was rounding lat & lng to less decimal places but after a second I realised that this is not a good approach. I also haven't found anything on the documentation since this is probably not a standard effect.

To sum up:

**Question**: with a bunch of overlays / markers with precise latitude and longitude, **how I can align markers to something like an invisible grid**?
Any hint would be very, very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I would do a grid constructor with two-dimensional array of cells, where cell will have a static size like 6px*6px or whatever you want and coords, it will be generated in a loop, then on zoom event just recalculate all this grid, when pass the closest marker to center of each grid

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- Determine width of the map (in pixels).
- Determine how many tiles your grid should have on this map
- Divide the width of the map by the number of tiles
- Hold this number
- Divide the maximum longitude by the same number of tiles (point 2)
- Divide the yet to place longitude by the result
- Multiply the result of that by the number you held before

ofcourse do the same for latitude

Answer (score 0):

It's all about segmenting the pixel values you get from `fromLatLngToDivPixel()` function. Try this, and play with `pixelLimit` variable.

```
var pixelLimit = 10;
var point = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.latlng);
var xPos = point.x - (point.x % pixelLimit) + "px";
var yPos = point.y - (point.y % pixelLimit) + "px";
div.style.left = xPos;
div.style.top = yPos;
```